# twm (Tab Window Manager): disabling keyboard bell

Tags: desktop, bell, twm

I would like to disable the keyboard bell in twm (Tab Window Manager). How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `xset` to disable it in a WM-independent way:

```
xset b off
```

Comment: where do I have to put this instruction? Should it go in `.twmrc` ?

Comment: @simona You can launch it as part of your display manager (`~/.xinitrc` if you use startx/xinit). I don't know if you can do that in `.twmrc`, I've not used it in many years.